# Checking for multiple images loaded

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, onload

I'm using the canvas feature of html5. I've got some images to draw on the canvas and I need to check that they have all loaded before I can use them.

I have declared them inside an array, I need a way of checking if they have all loaded at the same time but I am not sure how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
var color = new Array();
color[0] = new Image();
color[0].src = "green.png";
color[1] = new Image();
color[1].src = "blue.png";
```

Currently to check if the images have loaded, I would have to do it one by one like so:

```
color[0].onload = function(){
//code here
}
color[1].onload = function(){
//code here
}
```

If I had a lot more images, Which I will later in in development, This would be a really inefficient way of checking them all.

How would I check them all at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hackish way to do it is add the JS command in another file and place it in the footer. This way it loads last.

However, using jQuery(document).ready also works better than the native window.onload.

You are using Chrome aren't you?

Comment: Yah, the window.onload running early is a chrome bug. You can use browser sniffing with a setTimeout to delay it for chrome specifically.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Why is this marked as such?

Comment: Because the answer to /his/ question was "you are using a chrome and are seeing a bug." While adding an event listener to each image is one possible solution to a generic problem, it wasn't the one that solved /his/ problem.

Answer (score 33):

If you want to call a function when all the images are loaded, You can try following, it worked for me

```
var imageCount = images.length;
var imagesLoaded = 0;

for(var i=0; i<imageCount; i++){
    images[i].onload = function(){
        imagesLoaded++;
        if(imagesLoaded == imageCount){
            allLoaded();
        }
    }
}

function allLoaded(){
    drawImages();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Can't you simply use a loop and assign the same function to all onloads?

```
var myImages = ["green.png", "blue.png"];

(function() {
  var imageCount = myImages.length;
  var loadedCount = 0, errorCount = 0;

  var checkAllLoaded = function() {
    if (loadedCount + errorCount == imageCount ) {
       // do what you need to do.
    }
  };

  var onload = function() {
    loadedCount++;
    checkAllLoaded();
  }, onerror = function() {
    errorCount++;
    checkAllLoaded();
  };   

  for (var i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = onload; 
    img.onerror = onerror;
    img.src = myImages[i];
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `window.onload` which fires when all ***images***/frames and external resources are loaded:

```
window.onload = function(){
  // your code here........
};
```

So, you can safely put your image-related code in `window.onload` because by the time all images have already loaded.

**[More information here.](http://javascript.about.com/library/blonload.htm)**

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve it. I've implemented the window.onload event handler around the function caller that starts off the whole script but it still runs too early.

Comment: This also doesn't work if your images' DOM nodes are created after the window onload event.

Answer (score 3):

The solution with `Promise` would be:

```js
const images = [new Image(), new Image()]
for (const image of images) {
  image.src = 'https://picsum.photos/200'
}

function imageIsLoaded(image) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    image.onload = () => resolve()
    image.onerror = () => resolve()
  })
}

Promise.all(images.map(imageIsLoaded)).then(() => {
  alert('All images are loaded')
})
```

Comment: Why? what does `promise` do??

Comment: It waits until all images are loaded

Answer (score 1):

Just `onload` method in `for loop` does not solve this task, since `onload` method is executing asynchronously in the loop. So that larger images in the middle of a loop may be skipped in case if you have some sort of callback just for the last image in the loop.

You can use Async Await to chain the loop to track image loading synchronously.

```
function loadEachImage(value) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
      var thumb_img = new Image();
      thumb_img.src = value;
      thumb_img.onload = function () {
         console.log(value);
         resolve(value); // Can be image width or height values here
      }
   });
}

function loadImages() {
   let i;
   let promises = [];

   $('.article-thumb img').each(function(i) {
      promises.push(loadEachImage( $(this).attr('src') ));
   });

   Promise.all(promises)
      .then((results) => {
          console.log("images loaded:", results); // As a `results` you can get values of all images and process it
      })
      .catch((e) => {
         // Handle errors here
      });
}

loadImages();
```

But the disadvantage of this method that it increases loading time since all images are loading synchronously.

---

Also you can use simple `for loop` and run callback **after each iteration** to update/process latest loaded image value. So that you do not have to wait when smaller images are loaded only after the largest.

```
var article_thumb_h = [];
var article_thumb_min_h = 0;

$('.article-thumb img').each(function(i) {
   var thumb_img = new Image();
   thumb_img.src = $(this).attr('src');
   thumb_img.onload = function () {
      article_thumb_h.push( this.height ); // Push height of image whatever is loaded
      article_thumb_min_h = Math.min.apply(null, article_thumb_h); // Get min height from array
      $('.article-thumb img').height( article_thumb_min_h ); // Update height for all images asynchronously
   }
});
```

---

Or just use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13477381/5246900) to make a callback after all images are loaded.

It all depends on what you want to do. Hope it will help to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<div class="image-wrap" data-id="2">
<img src="https://www.hd-wallpapersdownload.com/script/bulk-upload/desktop-free-peacock-feather-images-dowload.jpg" class="img-load" data-id="1">
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin loader-2" style="font-size:24px"></i>
</div>

<div class="image-wrap" data-id="3">
<img src="http://diagramcenter.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/image.png" class="img-load" data-id="1">
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin loader-3" style="font-size:24px"></i>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var allImages = jQuery(".img-load").length;
        jQuery(".img-load").each(function(){
            var image = jQuery(this);
            jQuery('<img />').attr('src', image.attr('src')).one("load",function(){
                var dataid = image.parent().attr('data-id');
                console.log(dataid);
                 console.log('load');
            });
        });

    });

</script>
```